# Same code but still image and text alignment is getting changed for some buttons in footer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Below is my MenuPage code.

```
@section FooterSection
{
    <table class="footerButtonTableStyle">
        <tr class="footerButtonTRStyle">
            @foreach (DataRow item in Model[1].Rows)
            {
                if (footerButtonCount == 5) { break; } else { footerButtonCount++; }
                <td class="footerButtonTDStyle">
                    <img class="footerButtonImageSize" src="~/Content/img/fwDelete.png" alt="" /><br />
                    <div class="footerButtonCaptionFont">@item["Caption1"]</div>
                </td>
            }
            <td class="footerButtonTDStyle" onclick="onFooterButtonClick()">
                <img class="footerButtonImageSize" src="~/Content/img/fwDelete.png" alt="" /><br />
                <div class="footerButtonCaptionFont" id="buttonForTable">
                    More
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

This the second page.

```
@section FooterSection
{
    <table class="footerButtonTableStyle">
        <tr class="footerButtonTRStyle">
            @foreach (DataRow item in Model[0].Rows)
            {
                if (footerButtonCount == 5) { break; } else { footerButtonCount++; }
                <td class="footerButtonTDStyle">
                    <img class="footerButtonImageSize" src="~/Content/img/fwDelete.png" alt="" /><br />
                    <div class="footerButtonCaptionFont">@item["Caption1"]</div>
                </td>
            }
            <td class="footerButtonTDStyle" onclick="onFooterButtonClick()">
                <img class="footerButtonImageSize" src="~/Content/img/fwDelete.png" alt="" /><br />
                <div class="footerButtonCaptionFont" id="buttonForTable">
                    More
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

All the styles i have used with id and classes in my site.css file. All are same. And the footer is in my layout page. So where i am doing wrong?

Comment: The only difference I see is top one uses `Model[1].Rows` and bottom uses `Model[0].Rows`

Comment: @mattytommo, This is what i am thinking. Even on DOM explorer i am getting nothing different in the code. :(